# pretty printing nested arrays using templates

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array, pretty-print

I have the following code to pretty-print arrays -:

```
// Print an array
// Does not work on nested arrays !
template<typename T1, size_t arrSize>
void printArray( T1 const( & arr )[arrSize], std::ostream& out = std::cout )
{
    out << "[";
    if ( arrSize )
    {
        for ( size_t it = 0; it != arrSize - 1; ++it )
        {
            out << arr[it] << ", ";
        }
        // Print the last element separately to avoid the extra characters following it.
        out << arr[arrSize - 1];
    }
    out << "]";
}

int arr[5][5];

int main()
{
    printArray( arr[0] );
    printArray( arr );
}
```

Output -:

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>   [0x489040, 0x489054, 0x489068, 0x48907c, 0x489090]

Although it is working correctly in case of single-dimensional arrays, in case of multidimensional ones, the function prints the indivisual addresses of the arrays rather than their contents.

**Is there any way to print generic multidimensional arrays using a single function call?**

I am using GCC 4.9.2 with the `-std=c++14` flag.

Comment: You can use `std::array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have one function for array, one for single element:

```
// Print a single element (use in array version)
template<typename T>
void printArray(T const &e, std::ostream& out = std::cout )
{
    out << e;
}

// Print an (nested) array
template<typename T1, size_t arrSize>
void printArray(T1 const(& arr)[arrSize], std::ostream& out = std::cout )
{
    out << "[";
    const char* sep = "";
    for (const auto& e : arr)
    {
        out << sep;
        printArray(e, out);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    out << "]";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/JRdfR3)

Comment: and you could leave out the "if (arrSize)" condition